# Is ServletContext-removeAttribute needed in ServletContextListener-contextDestroyed

Tags: java, servlets

I saw a lot of source codes that developers coded like below in ServletContextListener implementation (example)

```
    public class ServletContextListenerImpl implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("attribute1", new Bean1());
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    sce.getServletContext().removeAttribute("attribute1");  //--- LINE_REMOVE
}
```

My question is Do we really need to have line marked "LINE_REMOVE" in above example?

I think we donot need it because when contextDestroyed executing, the servletContext is about to destroyed completely so its attributes will be removed too.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although typically it is not needed, it's possible the code you are looking at also has a custom [`ServletContextAttributeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextAttributeListener.html) which listens for these removals of context attributes and performs some action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to remove the attribute after `ServletContext` is destroyed. However, if you want to listen to attribute removal events, you can use `ServletContextAttributeListener`

Comment: Thanks. Your ideas is similar to @Sotirios Delimanolis ideas.